# How to make scrapy wait for request result before continuing to next line

Tags: scrapy

In my spider, I have some code like this:

```py
next_page_url = response.follow(
    url=self.start_urls[0][:-1]+str(page_number+1),
    callback=self.next_page
)

if next_page_url:
```

next_page looks like this:

```py
def next_page(self, response):
        next_page_count = len(<xpath I use>)
        if next_page_count > 0:
            return True
        else:
            return False
```

I need next_page_url to be set before I can continue the next segment of code.
This code essentially checks if the current page is the last page for some file writing purposes

Comment: There is https://github.com/rmax/scrapy-inline-requests but you should not use it for this. You should learn to use Scrapy with callbacks, passing information from one callback to another through `cb_kwargs` (or `meta` in old Scrapy versions)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer I ended up going with:

instead of checking if the next page exists and then continuing on current request, I made the request to the page, checked if I got a response, and if I didn't, I said that the previous page was the final page.

I did this by using the `meta` keyword in scrapy's Request library (`response.follow()`) to pass the current page's necessary tracking data into the new request